# Java JAXB - howto use generated beans

Tags: java, xml, jakarta-ee, xsd, jaxb

I'm on my first project for generating java beans from xsd files. The generation works perfectly well, but now I want to add some special features to the generated classes. Modifying the generated code would be a bad idea, because it would be lost as soon as someone updates the code.

I don't understand how to get beans with custom functionallity generated from the unmarshalling process. Can you please point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Those generated classes are just value objects, so it won't be really a good idea to add any custom logic in them. However if you just need to make those generated classes more usable with better getters/setter, fluid API, etc, you could add some [xjc plugins](http://java.net/projects/jaxb2-commons/pages/Home) or even write your own plugin.

Answer (score 1):

@EugeneKuleshov's answer is a good one.  additionally, i believe you can configure xjc to generate interfaces instead of classes, and then you can implement the interfaces using your own custom model classes.

Answer (score 0):

And what about extending the generated classes and overriding those methods you need?